# What happens to a partition leader whose connection to ZK breaks?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

Does it stop acting as the leader (i.e. stop serving produce and fetch
requests) returning the "not a leader for partition" exception? Or
does it keep thinking it's the leader?

If it's the latter, any connected consumers that wait for new requests
on that replica will do so in vain. Since the cluster controller will
elect a new partition leader, this particular replica will become
stale.

I would expect this node to do the former, but I'd like to check to
make sure. (I understand it's an edge case, and maybe not a realistic
one at that, but still.)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation), more specifically in the [Distribution](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation#intro_distribution) topic:

> *Each partition has one server which acts as the "leader" and zero or more servers which act as "followers". The leader handles all read and
>   write requests for the partition while the followers passively
>   replicate the leader. **If the leader fails, one of the followers will
>   automatically become the new leader.** Each server acts as a leader
>   for some of its partitions and a follower for others so load is well
>   balanced within the cluster.*

Considering that a loss of connection is one of the many kinds of failure, I'd say that your first hypothesis is more likely to happen.

Comment: I am aware of that bit in the documentation. I don't think it provides a conclusive answer to my question though.